# Load and dispose images with Libgdx

Tags: android, image, libgdx

I made an android app using libgdx but I have a problem of latency. After a few games, the application become very slow and I don't really know why. 
I think it's maybe because the loading of images and when I dispose them but I am not really sure.

This is my code :

I have a class Cell and in this one I load and dispose images:

```
TextureAtlas dotsAtlas = game.getAssets().get("dots.pack", TextureAtlas.class);
TextureRegion textureRegionRed = dotsAtlas.findRegion("red");
ImageButtonStyleRed = new ImageButton.ImageButtonStyle();
ImageButtonStyleRed.imageUp = new TextureRegionDrawable(textureRegionRed);

public void disposeCell(){
    dotsAtlas.dispose();
}
```

And in the class GameScreen, I have :

```
public void dispose(){
    skin.dispose();
    stage.dispose();
    batch.dispose();
    backgroundSprite.getTexture().dispose();
    generatorFont.dispose();
    othersAtlas.dispose();
    Cell.disposeCell();
}
```

Do I use Atlas,textures and dispose functions correctly to load images ?

Comment: Latency wouldn't be caused by failing to dispose of Textures. It's something else you haven't shown.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Do you know where it could come from?
Maybe from the fonts ?
I use FreeTypeFontParameter, FreeTypeFontGenerator and BitmapFont.
Do I need to dispose them ?

Comment: Could be a million things, can't guess. Try the LibGDX forum and provide more code.